# Problem with javascript Promise that never resolves

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, google-maps-api-3, promise

I created two custom promises that are identical except for the fact they work on different user inputs.
Both promises make use of Google Maps API v-3 classes and methods.

Strange thing is that whenever the first one is called it will never resolve and will always return a reject status.
Also, even if it not resolves, the promise code will still execute printing in console several `console.log()` I put as controls.

So those two are the promises:

```
var checkingDeparture = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    console.log('1. checkingDeparture called');  //first function control
    var newDeparture = '';
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        
    geocoder.geocode({'address': $('#startTransfer').val()}, (results, status) => {
        console.log('2. checkingDeparture geocoder called');   //second function control
        if(status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            coordPoint = new google.maps.LatLng(results[0].geometry.location.lat(), results[0].geometry.location.lng());
                
            if(google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(coordPoint, window.venicePolygon)) {
                console.log('3. checkingDeparture containsLocation called');   //third function control
                newDeparture = 'Piazzale Roma, Venezia, VE, Italia';
            }
            else {
                newDeparture = $('#startTransfer').val();
            }
        }
            
        console.log(newDeparture);   //function result control
        resolve(newDeparture);
    });
        
    reject('Sorry there was an error with checkingDeparture promise...');
});
    
var checkingDestination = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    console.log('1. checkingDestination called');   //first function control
    var newDestination = '';
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        
    geocoder.geocode({'address': $('#endTransfer').val()}, (results, status) => {
        console.log('2. checkingDestination geocoder called');   //second function control
        if(status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            coordPoint = new google.maps.LatLng(results[0].geometry.location.lat(), results[0].geometry.location.lng());
                
            if(google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(coordPoint, window.venicePolygon)) {
                console.log('3. checkingDestination containsLocation called');   //third function control
                newDestination = 'Piazzale Roma, Venezia, VE, Italia';
            }
            else {
                newDestination = $('#endTransfer').val();
            }
        }
            
        console.log(newDestination);   //function result control
        resolve(newDestination);
    });
        
    reject('Sorry there was an error with checkingDestination promise...');
});
```

And this is where they get called:

```
var checkedDeparture = checkingDeparture;
var checkedDestination = checkingDestination;
    
Promise.all([checkedDeparture, checkedDestination]).then(() => {
    console.log(checkedDeparture + checkedDestination);   //promise values control
    var request = {
        origin: checkedDeparture,
        destination: checkedDestination,
        travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
        unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC
    };
        
    directionsService.route(request, (result, status) => {
        console.log('4. checking value of origin: ' + request.origin);   //fourth function control
        console.log('5. checking value of destination:' + request.destination);   //fifth function control
        console.log('6. directionsService called');   //sixth function control
        if(status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
            //do things
        }
            
        else {
            directionsDisplay.setDirections({routes: []});
            theMap.setCenter(window.globalCenter);
        }
    });
}).catch(e => {
    console.log(e);
});
```

I cannot see where the error actually is espcially since `checkingDestination` seems to resolve properly. Also, as `checkingDeparture` never resolves (but still executes), all the code part chained with `.then()` will not be executed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your promises are rejected before they are resolved!

Promises by definition fulfill exactly once (whether its a promise or a rejection), and only the first is accepted. So if you write code like:

```
new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(() => resolve(), 1000)
  reject() // this runs first
})
```

it will never resolve, and always reject.

And that is exactly what you are doing.

You need to modify your promises to only reject once something went wrong (or after a timeout):

```
var checkingDeparture = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // snip
        
    geocoder.geocode({'address': $('#startTransfer').val()}, (results, status) => {
        // snip
        if (status === "error") { // Change this for a real check
          reject('Sorry there was an error with checkingDeparture promise...');
        } else {
           resolve(newDeparture);
        }
    });
        
    
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me! I was really missing that point. I also noticed that I was not passing the promise values when calling the concatenated fuction. Thanks!